# How to display map elements?

Tags: c++, qt, dictionary

I have this:

```
map<QString,City> cityList;
```

And this:

```
class City{
   list<ArrivalVertex> *arrivalList;
   list<DepartureVertex> *departureList;
}
```

I want to access *arrivalList inside the class City.
I've tried this:

```
for(map<QString,City>::iterator mapIter = cityList.begin() ; mapIter != cityList.end() ; mapIter++)
```

But, I can't to access the method "first()" and "second()" using the mapIter, as show in C++ examples. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I saw, but it didn't solve my problem.

Comment: post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: `first` and `second` and not methods, they are variables: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair

Comment: @Amartel, thank you! Sorry for my careless error.